# What to use to backup files, preserving ACLs?

Tags: acl, tar, backup, permissions

When using the tar utility to store files in backups one loses the extended ACLs.

Is there some commonly used and not hackish solution (like: create a script that will recrate the ACLs from scratch) to preserve the ACLs?

Comment: See also [this duplicate question](http://serverfault.com/q/39958/158888).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using tar

To create:

```
tar --acls -cpf backup.tar some-dir-or-file
```

To untar:

```
tar --acls -xpf backup.tar
```

Comment: `tar: unrecognized option '--acls'` does not work.

Comment: Fedora has non-standard GNU Tar patches that include `--acls`

Comment: In Debian, `tar` doesn't support `--acls` until jessie.  (See [bug #732071](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=732071).)  The feature is also available in the package from `wheezy-backports`.

Comment: Note that said `wheezy-backports` version of `tar` has a bug wrt the `--acls` option.  Tarball extraction using said option will assign acl's, even if the archive had none(!).  See [here](https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/lxc-containers-have-extended-permissions-acl-by-default.25367/).

Answer (score 14):

Actually, I believe the question was not about the (standard) file permission bits, but *extended* ACL information (see setfacl(1) or acl(5)).

To my knowledge, the unmodified GNU tar ignores ACL information.  (The man page for GNU tar 1.15.1 as shipped with RHEL 5.2 mentions switches --acls and --no-acls, but I haven't gotten them to work.)

However, the *star* program is able to back up and restore ACLs, if you select the *exustar* format:

```
star -c -p -acl artype=exustar -f archive.tar  files...
star -x -acl -f archive.tar
```

Star home page: http://cdrecord.berlios.de/new/private/star.html
Star is available in ubuntu, at least.

Comment: This looks like what I seek, I will have to take a look on that. Now I need to buy some more hours per day ;)

Comment: `star` is not available on Debian and does not seem to be maintained by a "team". The project is still alive and maintained after 30+ years though. Try `bsdtar` if you want something else.

Comment: after shutdown of belios you may find it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/s-tar/files/

Answer (score 10):

I'm looking for a solution as well so far I found this:

first do a getfactl from my folder

```
getfacl -R /a_folder > folder.acl
```

then do a regular tar

```
tar -czvf folder.tar.gz /a_folder
```

when I extract it

```
tar -xvf folder.tar.gz
```

do a setfacl for the permissions.

```
setfacl --restore=folder.acl
```

this works for me.

Comment: Thanks. Nothing worked for me on this page[i really mean it, i even compiled star from source, but it failed to do the job]. But this indeed did work. Though not elegant, but works perfect.

Answer (score 5):

```
rsync with the -A and/or -X options.
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use **`bsdtar`**.

`bsdtar` **backups extended ACL by default**, it uses the **same syntax** as `GNU tar`, and the archives it produces are readable by `GNU tar`.

The package and command name (under Debian based distributions) is `bsdtar`.

```
bsdtar cf archive.tar /my/folder/using/extd_acl 
bsdtar xf archive.tar
```

The 2nd (extract) command restores ACLs.

Comment: I can't get it to work, even though I'm sure it worked some time ago. Filed a bug, https://code.google.com/p/libarchive/issues/detail?id=329 .

Comment: Same here actually... I tried it on Debian 8 Jessie and it didn't work. :(

Comment: I am using it on Debian (x64, PC) since several years without any problem (wheezy, jessie, and currently stretch on several machines).

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a simple-to-use yet powerful solution, I'd recommend `rdiff-backup`.

Basically, it makes a copy of a source directory to a destination directory but it also saves additional information so you can go back in time to whenever you want.

And, of course, it preserves symlinks, special files, hardlinks, permissions, uid/gid ownership and modification times.

Answer (score 1):

From the tar Man Page.

> -p, --same-permissions, --preserve-permissions
>                    ignore umask when extracting files (the default for root)

It is not actually the act of archiving that alters the access permissions(ACLs), but the act of unpacking them.  Tar is very often used to distribute files from one user to another, and so it is thought convenient to apply a users [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) when they unpack.

To preserve the files previous permissions, simply ad a p for to your options.  For example

Straight tar:

```
tar xvp some-file
```

bz.tar:

```
tar xvjp some-file
```

gz.tar:

```
tar xvzp some-file
```

Comment: this does not work.

Comment: Furthermore tar automatically figures out what to extract.  There is no need to pass 'j' or 'z'.

Answer (score 0):

@silk

> When using the tar utility to store files in backups one loses the
> extended ACLs.
>
> Is there some commonly used and not hackish solution (like: create a
> script that will recrate the ACLs from scratch) to preserve the ACLs?

When creating/extracting the archive you need to use both the `--acls` **and** `--xattrs` options and of-course have the proper permissions to read/write those [acl](/questions/tagged/acl) and [xattr](/questions/tagged/xattr).

### Examples:

#### 1. Creating the archive:

```
ZSTD_CLEVEL=19 tar --acls --xattrs -caPf systemd-network-conf.tzst --directory=/etc systemd/network systemd/networkd.conf.d
```

The above will create a `zstd` compressed `tar` archive, using compression level `19`, while preserving the ACL's and extended attributes.

- The `.tzst` extension means "a [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) archive using [zstd](/questions/tagged/zstd) compression", just like `tgz` is for a [gzip](/questions/tagged/gzip)'ed version etc.
- The compression level used by the implicit `zstd` compressor is set by the provided `ZSTD_CLEVEL` environment variable at start on same line.
- See man pages: `tar(1)` and `zstd(1)`.

#### 2. Extracting that archive:

```
sudo tar --acls --xattrs -xvf systemd-network-conf.tzst
```

The above will create, in your current directory, a sub-directory named `systemd` because that's the common root-dir inside the archive.

- All settings you had set using [chown](/questions/tagged/chown)/[chmod](/questions/tagged/chmod)/[setfacl](/questions/tagged/setfacl) in the originals, will be preserved in the extracted version.

#### 3. Comparing original and extracted file attributes.

```bash
{cd /etc; getfacl -R systemd/network systemd/networkd.conf.d} >original.acl; cd -
getfacl -R systemd/network systemd/networkd.conf.d >extracted.acl
diff -u original.acl extracted.acl
```

- You should see no output from the first two lines because it is redirected to a file.
  *(Exception for first line, which will output your current directory due to the last `cd -` as separate command, which just restores your current directory.)*
- You should see no output from the diff line either, because there's no difference.