# Compression / archiving that keeps permissions and file owner?

Tags: permissions, compression, archive

I know that similar questions have been asked about permissions, but which form of compression or archiving keeps the permissions and file owners of each file and directory?

I was considering the `tar.gz` format, but would this be right?

I need to move 37GB of files and directories to another server and need everything to be exactly the same when uncompressed.

Comment: `man tar` explains all this...you do have to actually read it tho (see e.g., "Handling of Attributes").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both traditional archiving tools [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)) and [cpio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpio) preserve ownership and Unix permissions (user/group/other) as well as timestamps (with cpio, be sure to pass `-m` when extracting). If you don't like their [arcane syntax](https://xkcd.com/1168/)¹, you can use their POSIX replacement [pax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pax_(Unix)) (`pax -w -pe`) All of these output an uncompressed archive; pipe the archive into a tool like `gzip` or `xz` to compress it (GNU tar has options to do the compression). Users and groups are identified by their name; GNU tar has an option .

None of these tools preserve modern features such as ACL, capabilities, security contexts or other extended attributes.

Some versions of tar can store ACL. See [What to use to backup files, preserving ACLs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391/what-to-use-to-backup-files-preserving-acls) With GNU tar, pass `--acls` both when creating and extracting the archive.

A squashfs filesystem, as [suggested by mikeserv](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/219790), stores capabilities and extended attributes including SELinux context, but not ACL. (You need [versions that aren't too antique](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=756809#c5).) If you have both ACL and security contexts, you can use a squashfs filesystem, and save the ACL by running `getfacl -R` at the root of the original filesystem and restore them after extracting the files with `setfacl --restore`.

If you want to save absolutely everything including ACL, subsecond timestamps, extended attributes and filesystem-specific attributes, you can clone the filesystem. The downside of this approach is that you can't conveniently directly write a compressed copy. The ultimate way to clone the filesystem is to copy the block device; of course this is wasteful in that it copies the empty space. Alternatively, create a filesystem that's large enough to store all the files and use `cp -a` with the `cp` command from GNU coreutils to copy the files; GNU cp is pretty good at copying everything including non-traditional features such as extended attribute and ACLs.

¹  <sub>Though this one is really overblown.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

If you're talking about linux systems then another option for you is [squashfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS). It can often achieve very high compression ratios - and the compression process itself is multi-threaded - which means that you can apply all processor cores to the compression task.

A squashfs archive differs from most other kinds in that it is a file-system. If you've ever booted a linux live disc then you've very likely already seen this in action - very nearly all of these work by mounting a squashfs archive as their root file-system. squashfs is supported in vanilla linux kernels since version 2.6.34. And so it is fairly universal to any modern linux system.

Squash supports any of gzip, lzma, lzo, xz, or *(since kernel 3.19)* lz4 compression methods. To mount and access the contents of a squash archive you shouldn't need any tools at all and can just do:

```
mount ./img.sfs /mnt; cd /mnt
```

...to get at it. The contents of the archive will then be provided you by the kernel's native [vfs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/fs/vfstour.html) as a read-only mount, and you can read all files within in the same way you would any other kind of file - and without having to decompress the archive *(which is handled on the fly into disk-cache on an as-needed basis by the linux kernel itself)*. In fact, with the latest kernels' lz4 support, you can likely do this at *native speed* *(and perhaps even faster in some cases)* as well - though there will be increased cpu-usage for squashed file access.

To create or decompress a squashfs archive you will need the squashfs-tools package installed. It is not generally installed by default by any distribution of which I am aware, but neither am I aware of any distribution which does not provide the package via package-manager. Once installed you can create an archive like:

```sh
echo 'this is my new file' >~/Downloads/newfile.txt
mksquashfs ~/Downloads ./mysqsh.sfs -comp xz
```

---

```
Parallel mksquashfs: Using 6 processors
Creating 4.0 filesystem on ./mysqsh.sfs, block size 131072.
[===================================================-] 1018/1018 100%

Exportable Squashfs 4.0 filesystem, xz compressed, data block size 131072
    compressed data, compressed metadata, compressed fragments, compressed xattrs
    duplicates are removed
Filesystem size 12592.01 Kbytes (12.30 Mbytes)
    57.19% of uncompressed filesystem size (22019.04 Kbytes)
Inode table size 8482 bytes (8.28 Kbytes)
    23.91% of uncompressed inode table size (35477 bytes)
Directory table size 10210 bytes (9.97 Kbytes)
    42.90% of uncompressed directory table size (23802 bytes)
Xattr table size 3976 bytes (3.88 Kbytes)
    48.67% of uncompressed xattr table size (8170 bytes)
Number of duplicate files found 61
Number of inodes 1064
Number of files 926
Number of fragments 68
Number of symbolic links  6
Number of device nodes 0
Number of fifo nodes 0
Number of socket nodes 0
Number of directories 132
Number of ids (unique uids + gids) 1
Number of uids 1
    mikeserv (1000)
Number of gids 1
    mikeserv (1000)
mksquashfs ... 7.08s user 0.35s system 462% cpu 1.607 total
```

As you can see - it clearly respects file permissions - and even preserves and respects extended file-system file attributes *(xattrs)* in most cases. And the compression ratio you see noted there is *in addition to* my regular file-system's default lzo compression - *(my root fs is btrfs and all files are compressed w/ lzo already)* - which is not to mention that much of *`~/Downloads`* is occupied by downloaded compressed archives in the first place.

It is immediately mountable as a proper file-system in its own right:

```sh
 sudo mount ./mysqsh.sfs /mnt;   \
 cd /mnt; cat newfile.txt; cd -; \
 sudo umount /mnt
```

---

```
this is my new file
```

As always, root permissions are generally required for arbitrary mounts, but a squashfs mount can be named like any other in `/etc/fstab` if you desire it.

And last, you don't need any elevated privileges to decompress a squashfs archive, only the `unsquashfs` tool *(which is also provided in the squashfs-tools package)*:

```sh
unsquashfs -d /tmp/mysqsh ./mysqsh.sfs; \
cd /tmp/mysqsh; cat newfile.txt
```

---

```
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 6 processors
933 inodes (1025 blocks) to write
[=================================================|] 1025/1025 100%

created 927 files
created 132 directories
created 6 symlinks
created 0 devices
created 0 fifos

this is my new file
```

Comment: But it doesn't preserve ownership.  Your answer is *completely* unrelated to the question and I would downvote it if it didn't contain so much useful information for *other* problems.

That said, I would sure love to add file ownership capabilities to squashfs, but it seems there's many complexities involved. :(

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  tar retains the owner and permissions.

Wikipedia: [tar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing))

> The archive data sets created by tar contain various file system parameters, such as time stamps, **ownership**, **file access permissions**, and directory organization.